# how to query duplicate string entry in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, string, comparison, duplicates

I have a program which has a function to show AT LEAST 2 duplicated similar string in MySQL records, I have a current implementation which works well BUT too slow for 300K records.

Example CONTACT table entries :

```
id (int)| name (string) | phone (string)
-----------------------------------------
1       | mike          | 081239812345678
2       | jhon          | 082222212345678
3       | rudy          | 081237712345678
4       | lucy          | 081237712345123
5       | lily          | 081244412345678
```

I need to get record belong to "mike, jhon, rudy and lily" because 8 of their last phone number digits are the same (duplicated), but record belong to lucy is ignored (because no other record has similar 8 digit ending number)

My current method is to use 2 queries like :

My first query :

```
"select right(phoner, 8) as myRight
    , count(*) as totdup
     from contact
     group by myRight
     having totdup > 1";
```

from this query I can get the value of "myRight" then I execute second query to get the detail:

```
"select * from contact where phone like '%$myRight'";
```

My question is HOW to speed up the process because I have 300K records and it takes around 20 minutes for this query, also I am looking to simplify the query by only using 1 query but I do not know how, I have been struggle with this problem for couple days now, your help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the (8) rightmost characters of the phonenumbers in reverse order then
Your table will have the following fields:

```
id (int)| name (string) | phone (string)  | phonerev (string)
----------------------------------------------------
1       | mike          | 081239812345678 | 876543218932180
2       | jhon          | 082222212345678 | 876543212222280
3       | rudy          | 081237712345678 | 876543217732180
4       | lucy          | 081237712345123 | 321543217732180
5       | lily          | 081244412345678 | 876543214442180
```

you can do a query like:

```
select right(phone,8) as myRight
from contact c1
inner join contract c2 on (left(c1.phonerev,8) = left(c2.phonerev,8) 
                           and c1.id <> c2.id)
group by left(phonerev,8)
```

Make sure you set an index on phonerev

You can unify the query by doing:

```
select c1.*
from contact c1
inner join contract c2 on (left(c1.phonerev,8) = left(c2.phonerev,8) 
                           and c1.id <> c2.id)
```

This will allow the use of an index on the phonenumber

If you just store the 8 rightmost chars in reverse order, then the query becomes:

```
select right(phone,8) as myRight
from contact c1
inner join contract c2 on (c1.phonerev,8 = c2.phonerev 
                           and c1.id <> c2.id)
group by phonerev;
```

Which is even faster.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running a loop over the result rows from the first query and executing the second query once for each such row.

I'd suggest putting the first result into a temporary table and then doing

```
SELECT contact.* FROM contact JOIN temporary
 WHERE right(contact.phoner, 8) = temporary.myRight
```

Putting an index on the temporary table will probably improve your performance even more.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of MySQL you're using, this might work:

```
select *
from contact
where RIGHT(phone, 8) IN (
 select right(phone, 8) as myRight
     from contact
     group by myRight
     having COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Johan, you gave me a good direction to speed up the query, I added a new field for rightmost 8 char of phone, this avoid using "right(phone, 8)" in the query.

@Will A, thanks for your help but the query actually slower than my current solution, I dont know why.

@LHMathies, your idea is good, but making temp table for storing myRight is not applicable for my server/database condition.

Thank you guys~